# use base instead of parent in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, orm, dbix-class

Any idea why the DBIx::Class uses `use base` instead of `use parent`?

see [this](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08195/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Example.pod) for instance.

Correct me i'm wrong, but isn't it `use base` deprecated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For compatibility with older Perls. `use parent` was added in 5.10, but `DBIx::Class` still supports Perl 5.8.

Technically, the perldocs state that `use base` is "discouraged" rather than formally deprecated, implying that it is certainly not going to go away any time soon. But if you know your code is targeting Perl 5.10, `use parent` is better.

Comment: parent.pm can be easily installed from CPAN. cpantesters show that it works even on perl 5.6.1.